# Making content responsible between fixed divs

Tags: html, css

so here is what I currently have. The red marked stuff is fixed, so it will stay on screen. Only the content in the middle is actually scrollable.
[image]

I currently have all the fixed like this (example on the right bar with the 3 game icons) in my css:

```css
                 margin-top: 102px;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 123px;
```

And my content is basicly just a fixed size with a margin-left.
So it looks fine, right? My problem is tho, if the middle content isn't scrollable (trough for example no games) the scrollbar on the right disappears and a gap appears, obviously.
[image]

How can I make this responsible, so it fits everytime?

Comment: Do you have width:auto; and overflow-y:auto; for the non-fixed div?

Comment: c.early I dont, if I add it to the main content it halves the page (approximately until the header width)

Comment: Could you post your code in a jsfiddle?  It's difficult to figure out the problem if not.  Have you checked you don't have a margin or padding set to the right of the scrollable content?

Comment: c.early the problem is that I have a static width of the main content (1282px in this case) and the fixed right bar is fixed on the right side. so as soon the scrollbar vanishes theres a gap.

Comment: you cant force a content to be responsible, it needs time to grow and one day can become on its own...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery to detect the width of the browser window, minus the left and right areas and set the width of the content area to the remaining value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var rightColumnWidth = 80;
    var leftColumnWidth = 250;
    var contentColumn = windowWidth - rightColumnWidth - leftColumnWidth;

    $("#idOfContentArea").width(contentColumn);
});
```

Comment: yup that works, altough I don't like hardcoded solutions like that, at least it works

Comment: You can 'grab' the width of your right and left columns too if you give them an id. That way you don't have to hardcode the values; var leftColumnWidth = $('#leftCol").width();

Answer (score 0):

Just try to remove the width rule from the content and gives it margin left and right equals to the sidebars' width.
The width of the content should adjust accordingly with the space between the sidebars this way.

This is a full css solution, no jQuery needed.